# Breaking up a long line of values in a box

Tags: php, html, css, space

The array `$carry_over` returns a really long list of entries, too long for my printout page. I would love to make it in such a way that after 4 entries, it breaks and goes to the next line and breaks at the next four entries until all entries are in.
How can i do this?
Thanks

```
echo "<table class=\"altrowstable\" bgcolor = gold >\n";
 $count = 0;
echo "<tr align= \"center\">\n"; 
$carry_over = array(); 
$score_count = mysql_numrows($query8);
echo "<td>"."Failed: ";
if($score_count !== 0){
    while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) { 
        echo "<th>".$row8['course_code']."</th>";
if ( $count == 7 ){
     echo "</tr>\n"; 
    echo "</table>"; 

   }
  }
 }
```

**Update** :  Now only the first 7 entries are covered inside the table tags, the subsequent ones are outside the table tags. How can i put them in the tabke tags?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could try:

```
$count = 0;
echo "<tr>";
while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query8)) { 
    echo "<th>" . $row8['course_code'] . "</th>";
    $count++;
    if(count == 4) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $count = 0;
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. When i tried it only the first four were covered in the table, the rest were outside the table design.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a table for list data. Instead of using a `<table>`, you *should* be using a `<ul>` with `<li>` for each element. This can then be styled so that each `li` has `display: inline-block;`, for example.

Comment: While this does offer a good alternative, it still doesn't fully answer the question. For example, you could elaborate on how to style the list item's to appear the same as the intended appearance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what the table looks like from the code above, but you can put an iterator in to count to four then wrap. You also may want to check out [Wordwrap](https://www.php.net/word%20wrap)